# What is the missing operator in this sql query?

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is from a VB.Net program:

```
Dim cmd As String = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Employee Name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%';"
```

When it executes, it says that there is a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Employee Name LIKE '%some text here%'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please don't concat SQL statements like this, use SQL parameters.

Comment: Granted this code may be subject to SQL injection but a lot depends on context. The cost of heightened security may not be worth the expense if there is zero exposure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Employee Name` is the name of your column then you have to put square brackets around it to avoid confusing the parser.

```
Dim cmd As String = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE " & _ 
                    "[Employee Name] LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%';"
```

And remember that string concatenation to build sql query is [a real danger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).
A parameterized query is always the way to go.

Supposing that you are working with Sql Server

```
Dim cmd As String = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE " & _ 
                    "[Employee Name] LIKE @name"
Using con = new SqlConnection(.....)
Using cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, con)
   con.Open()
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" & TextBox1.Text & "%")
   Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        .....
   End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: it should be a comment not an answer yar

Comment: A comment? Why, this is the error and this is the answer

Comment: you have updated your answer when I wrote the comment it was not clear it was looking like a comment

Comment: Why exactly is it bad to concat sql strings? It gets the job done for me.

Comment: until someone enters `'; DELETE Employees; --`

Comment: Look carefully at the link posted above (real danger) and, if you are not convinced then try to write an employee name containing a single quote (O'Brian for example)